# findSuccess method itemsList is always undefined

Tags: javascript, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I am new to Tizen working on a small application I am not able to figure out what is the problem.

When I am using these lines before it was working fine but now

```
var audioOnly = new tizen.AttributeFilter('type', 'EXACTLY', 'AUDIO');
    tizen.content.find(findSuccess, findError, null, audioOnly);
```

Here is code for `findSuccess` which add lines in log

```
findSuccess(itemsList){
        console.log('total items:'+itemsList);
        console.log(itemsLis.name+'etc..');
 }
```

In `findSuccess` method `itemsList` is always undefined, no object fetched even when there are files in the device. All settings are proper permissions for read and write is set in *config.xml* file.

This is Tizen webapi code

Comment: Where is your itemsList?

Comment: findSuccess is callback method which receive array as an argument

Comment: please update and add the findSuccess method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with below code.

```
function findSuccess(items) {
        for ( var i in items) {
            console.log('Item title: ' + items[i].title);
            console.log('Item URI: ' + items[i].contentURI);
            console.log('Item type: ' + items[i].type);
       }
    }

    function onError(error) {
         console.log('Error: ' + error);
      }


 // Function to get list of all certain media files
    function getSelectedMediaList() {
       var mediasource = null;
       mediasource = tizen.content;
       var type = 'AUDIO';
       var filter = new tizen.AttributeFilter("type", "EXACTLY", type);
       try {
             mediasource.find(findSuccess, onError, null, filter);
       } catch (exc) {
            console.log("findItems exception:" + exc.message);
       }
   }

    getSelectedMediaList();
```

Don't forget to add privileges in **config.xml**

```
 <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/content.write"/>
 <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/content.read"/>
```

Comment: I am using same similar code to get data there is some issue in application context but still not able to fix it. as i have created new application code worked fine

Comment: any way thanks Iqbal hossain for help as i used your code it worked now in same application can i use this code in my application? if you agreed

Comment: absulately ...why not ... and if my code solve your problem please mark it as accepted answer